# An empty line in csv output file using xslt

Tags: java, csv, xslt

Hi i am have an XML file and trying to convert it using xslt. But issue is i get a white line before the output.How do i eliminate it.
Below is my XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserInfo xmlns="http://XXXXXX">
    <User>
            <UserName>MNO</UserName>
            <Userid>1234</Userid>
            <address>xyz</address>
            <city>ABC</city>
            <state>XX</state>
            <zip>000000</zip>
    </User>
    <User>
            <UserName>DEF</UserName>
            <Userid>4567</Userid>
            <address>IJK</address>
            <city>GHI</city>
            <state>XX</state>
            <zip>000000</zip>
    </User>

</UserInfo>
```

below is my xsl

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
UserName,Userid,address,city,state,zip
<xsl:for-each select="//User">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(UserName,',',Userid,',',address,',',city,',',state,',',zip,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When ever i run the above i get a white line first and then the output.

```csv
vendorName,vendorId,vendorTaxId,addressLine1,addressLine2,city,state,zip
MNO,1234,xyz,ABC,XX,000000
DEF,4567,IJK,GHI,XX,000000
```

I get the white space above the nodes(UserName,UserId etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xsl:text` to output literal text, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>UserName,Userid,address,city,state,zip&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//User">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(UserName,',',Userid,',',address,',',city,',',state,',',zip,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The way you have it now, the entire text node is written to the output - including the line break between `<xsl:template match="/">` and `UserName`.

Comment: Also tell OP about the default namespace that has to be accounted for in his `xsl:for-each/@select`.

Comment: I did the same but it didnt worked.It first outputs an empty line and then the data

Comment: @rockstar_77 You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGdm  -- Note that I have removed the default namespace  declaration from your input. As noted above by kjhughes, you could not have received the claimed output using your code.

Comment: It worked.Thank you so much.I have realized the mistake i did.